# Azure Approach to proactive Logging

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am working on Azure web API which uses Log4Net Application Insight appender to track traces. We are planning to use the Application Insight SDK directly (TrackTrace(), TrackEvent()) in order to use built-in alerting features.

However it does seem like, Azure is not supporting trace or event alerts but only metric alerts. So we got some issue there.

If I go one step back, web API is invoked by number of Logic Apps runs in x time intervals. Logic App simply calls web API (business logic is here) and it log all information/managed exceptions.

The main requirement is to be proactive when an exception happens like sending a mail to technical inbox. Secondary requirement is notify sources, if it got any data issues.

Any suggestion on our approach please, what we can do more to fulfill our requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [App Insights Exception Alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-alerts#what-are-good-alerts-to-set). It is possible to set alerts for rates of exceptions in a defined time period.

[Set up Exception alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-exceptions#exception-performance-counters)

You can also invoke webhooks to perform additional actions when the alert is fired.

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers

Comment: This is where I got confused, application insight alerts fire when a state changes. My requirement is fire an customize alert for every exception.

For example, let's say we found couple of data validation failures.
I would like to fire couple of alerts for relevant validation failures. Furthermore I would like to make the alert template more friendly for non IT teams as well.

Comment: In a very large scale application, firing an alert for every exception occurrence can be excessively noisy. So, a better way to scale would be to look at exceptions/ failures, at regular intervals and then alert based on it. As to the alert template, you should look at the webhooks option. When the alert fires, it can invoke a webhook and you can set up a service to action on the alert however you see fit (Template setting, additional correlation data etc)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sreejit for your suggestion.

To conclude the answer, what's the preferred engine to process alerts please, through application insight or log analytics?

1. application insight only support metric alerts only, so the application exceptions need to be flagged as custom metrics as opposed to traces. 
   [TelemetryClient --> TrackTrace() vs TrackMetric()]
2. If we go for log analytics, we can use custom events. Then use alert management solution in OMS workspace. Perhaps even use of a separate logic app to built the logic of sending alerts. 
   [TelemetryClient --> TrackEvent()]